# How do I scrape this text from an HTML <span id> using Python, Selenium, and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm working on creating a web scraping tool that generates a .csv report by using Python, Selenium, beautifulSoup, and pandas.

Unfortunately, I'm running into an issue with grabbing the "data-date" text from the HTML below. I am looking to pull the "2/4/2020" into the .csv my code is generating.

```
<span class="import-popover"><span id="LargeHeader_glyphStatus" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign white"></span><b><span id="LargeHeader_statusText">Processing Complete</span></b><span id="LargeHeader_dateText" data-date="2/4/2020" data-delay="1" data-step="3" data-error="False">, Last Processed 2/5/2020</span></span>
```

My python script starts off with the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')

lastdatadate=[]
lastprocesseddate=[]
```

Then I have it log in to a website, enter my un/pw credentials, and click the continue/login button.

From there, I am using the following to parse the html, scrape the website, and pull the relevant data/text into a .csv:

```
content = driver.page_source
soup = bs(content, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'large-header-welcome'}):
    datadate=a.find(?????)
    processeddate=a.find('span', attrs={'id':'LargeHeader_dateText'})
    lastdatadate.append(datadate.text)
    lastprocesseddate.append(processeddate.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Last Data Date':lastdatadate,'Last Processed Date':lastprocesseddate}) 
df.to_csv('hqm.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

So far, I've got it working for the "last processed date" component of the HTML, but I am having trouble getting it to pull the "last data date" from the HTML. It's there, I just don't know how to have python find it. I've tried using the find method but I have not been successful.

I've tried googling around and checking here for what I should try, but I've come up empty-handed so far. I think I'm having trouble what to search for.

Any insight would be much appreciated as I am trying to learn and get better. Thanks!

edit: here is a closer look of the HTML:

```
 <div class="large-header-welcome">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h3 class="welcome-header">Welcome, <span id="LargeHeader_fullname">Rhett</span></h3>
                <p class="">
                    <b>Site:</b> <span id="LargeHeader_Name">redacted</span>
                    <br />
                    <span class="import-popover"><span id="LargeHeader_glyphStatus" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign white"></span><b><span id="LargeHeader_statusText">Processing Complete</span></b><span id="LargeHeader_dateText" data-date="2/4/2020" data-delay="1" data-step="3" data-error="False">, Last Processed 2/5/2020</span></span>
                </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is that span tag inside anchor tag or what?

Comment: I don't think it's in an anchor tag. It appears to be inside of a div tag, but I could be wrong! I'll edit my description and add it in. Thanks!

Comment: check if my answer helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find one element use find()

```
processeddate=soup.find('span', attrs={'id':'LargeHeader_dateText'}).text
```

to find multple elements use

```
for item in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'id':'LargeHeader_dateText'}):
    processeddate=item.text
```

---

Or you can use css selector select()

```
for item in soup.select('#LargeHeader_dateText'):
    processeddate=item.text
```

---

**EDIT**

To get the attribute value `data-date` use following code

```
lastdatadate=[]
for item in soup.find_all('span',attrs={"id": "LargeHeader_dateText","data-date": True}):
    processeddate=item['data-date']
    lastdatadate(processeddate)
    lastdatadate.append(processeddate)
```

Or css selector.

```
lastdatadate=[]
for item in soup.select('#LargeHeader_dateText[data-date]'):
    processeddate=item['data-date']
    print(processeddate)
    lastdatadate.append(processeddate)
```

Both will give same output.however later one faster execution.

Comment: Adding to this answer, to extract the `data-date` values you would then just need to do `data_date = item['data-data']`

Comment: Thanks @KunduK and @bnlucas! Warning: I'm a novice, but I am looking for multiple elements. I've got "processed date" working - I'm just having trouble with getting the text from the HTML for "data-date" (in this ex., "2/4/2020").

Comment: Sounds like I should change it to this?:  ~~~for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'large-header-welcome'}):                                   datadate=item['data-date']                                                                                                   lastdatadate.append(datadate.text)~~~  Bah, sorry I can't figure out how to format code in a reply here. :\\

Comment: for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'large-header-welcome'}): datadate=item['data-date'] lastdatadate.append(datadate.text)

Comment: Thanks @Kunduk ! I'm using console and I found that if I do the following I can get some of the html/text I'm looking for: datadate = soup.select('#LargeHeader_dateText[data-date]')    and then when I print(datadate) it returns: [<span data-date="2/11/2020" data-delay="1" data-error="False" data-step="3" id="LargeHeader_dateText">, Last Processed 2/12/2020</span>]     I'm wondering how to get/return the "2/11/2020" from here. Almost there!!

Comment: Check my last example under Edit section.That will give you the attribute value of data-date

Comment: Finally got it working!! Thanks again, @Kunduk for throwing all that python and html knowledge at me - that was so helpful!